# While debugging, can I have access to the Redux store from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have unit tests for my `reducers`. However, when I'm debugging in the browser, I want to check if my actions have been called correctly and whether the state has been modified accordingly.

I'm looking for something like:

```
window._redux.store
```

... in the browser so I can type that on the console and check how things are going.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: As a side note, you might consider using the [Redux Devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) along with [the `LogMonitor`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools-log-monitor) to visualize your actions and resulting states.

Comment: Talking about security, in production build mode, is it possible read store from browser console?

Comment: @JRichardsz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507052/redux-security-is-it-possible-to-access-store-data#comment74068933_43507052

Answer (score 198, accepted):

## How to view redux store on any website, with no code changes

#### Update Nov 2019

The react devtools have changed since my original answer. The new `components` tab in chrome's devtools still has the data, but you may have to search a little bit more.

1. open chrome devTools
2. select react devtool's `Components` tab
3. click on the top-most node and look in right-hand column for `store` to be shown
4. repeat step 3 down the tree until you find the `store` (for me it was the 4th level)
5. Now you can follow the steps below with `$r.props.store.getState()`

[image: Example screenshot]

#### Original Answer

If you have react developer tools running you can use `$r.store.getState();` with **no changes to your codebase**.

**Note:** You have to open the react devtool in your developer tools window first to make this work, otherwise you will get a `$r is not defined` error

1. open developer tools
2. click the React tab
3. ensure the provider node (or topmost node) is selected
4. then type `$r.store.getState();` or `$r.store.dispatch({type:"MY_ACTION"})` into your console

Comment: Note: for this to work, you need to store the `state` as a property on your root component. If you follow [the directions](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#passing-the-store) and have the `<Provider>` as the top-level component, this will work fine. Just got bit by moving it around!

Comment: Hi @S.Kiers and thanks for this great tip. But since react developer tools also work on production websites, it looks like react developer tools isn't required to connect to the store. Would love it if someone had a nice js command to replace the need for react devtools (eg if wanting to show something on somebody else computer)

Also, do you have any tips regarding production environments ? I can see that facebook's store isn't accessible from window.$r, and this sounds a bit more secure that way. Wondering if I shouldn't do the same thing with my product

Comment: @Fandekasp Facebook doesn't use redux. Your redux store will always be available to someone with enough will. :)

Comment: Mine says `$r` doesn't exist.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai did you read the full answer. There are things you need to do to make this work. Or perhaps the site doesn't use redux?

Comment: Try `$r.state.store.getState()`

Comment: While running https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/ tutorial, I came upon this problem too. I did not find a way to do this in FireFox dev tools, I had to use Chrome.

In Chrome, I clicked Components, then selected the Provider. In the pane below, I clicked console. Then, to get the state, I typed:

$r.props.store.getState()

Comment: Looks like `$r` refers to currently selected component in the `Components` section of Dev Tools. I don't seem to be able to access the entire `store` through `$r`, maybe because I'm using hooks everywhere, but I get to see the part of the store that my component can see, which is almost as good, and sometimes more to the point!

Comment: `$r.hooks[0].subHooks[0].subHooks[0].value.store.getState()` works for those components that `useSelector`... Ob., YMMV depending on hooks you use...

Comment: I had to use `$r.props.store`

Comment: I can't click to console without the Component being unselected. Any ideas?

Comment: once you pop open components $r will exist

Comment: is this also possible in production builds?

Comment: @eamanola yes, it works on production build. Although, depending on the structure, you may have to tweak it a little

Comment: If above doesn't work then try `$r.props.store.getState()`. Make sure the devtools is open as shown in the image.

Comment: not gonna lie. this tool sucks. should be 100% easy for devs to debug stuff like this.

Answer (score 75):

`let store = createStore(yourApp); 
 window.store = store;`

Now you can access the store from window.store in the console like this:

`window.store.dispatch({type:"MY_ACTION"})`

Comment: and can also access the state:
`window.store.getState()`

Comment: How do you know `yourApp` name in production?

Comment: This solution assumes that you can modify the source code

Answer (score 29):

The recommended solution doesn't work for me.

The correct command is:

```
$r.props.store.getState()
```

Comment: it should be a comment to these answer

Comment: It doesnt work right now

Answer (score 15):

You can use a logging middleware [as described in the Redux Book](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#seven-examples):

```
/**
 * Logs all actions and states after they are dispatched.
 */
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd(action.type)
  return result
}

let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore)

let yourApp = combineReducers(reducers)
let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(yourApp)
```

Alternatively, you could change the logging to just append to a global array (your `window._redux`) and you could look in the array when you needed information on a particular state.

Comment: Or even better, use a library like [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger)

Comment: If you're importing the reducers like this: import reducers from './reducers/' then you can just use let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers) as the './reducers/' file typically will have combineReducers in it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [Next JS](https://nextjs.org/), you can access the store by: `window.__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__.getState()`
 You can also dispatch actions, just look at the options you have in `window.__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__`

Answer (score 7):

Another answer suggests adding the store to the window, but if you just want access to the store as an object, you can define a getter on the window.

This code needs to be added where you've configured your store - in my app, this is the same file as where `<Provider store={store} />` is called.

Now you can type `reduxStore` in the console to get an object - and `copy(reduxStore)` to copy it to the clipboard.

```
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'reduxStore', {
    get() {
      return store.getState();
    },
  });
```

You can wrap this in an `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')` to disable it in production.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to see store state for debugging you could do this:

```
#import global from 'window-or-global'
const store = createStore(reducer)
const onStateChange = (function (global) {
  global._state = this.getState()
}.bind(store, global))
store.subscribe(onStateChange)
onStateChange()
console.info('Application state is available via global _state object.', '_state=', global._state)
```

Answer (score 0):

With react developer tools:

```
const store = [...__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent.internalInstancesById.values()].find(e=>e.elementType.name==="Provider").pendingProps.store
```

Comment: gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined` error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the various methods of the redux state and view it as well, you can store it as a temp global variable and access it via the console. In my solution I used Firefox with React Dev Tools installed.
[image]

1. Open React dev tools, find the topmost component where the `store` is visible.
2. Right click the `store` variable in the inspector window and click on `Store as global variable`. As soon as you do this, you should see some variable name output to the browser's console. Something like `$reactTemp0`.
3. You can now use this variable to access the store and its methods. So if I wanted to execute a get method, I could say `$reactTemp0.getState()` and view the entire state. You can also use other methods, like `dispatch`, but there might be better ways of testing those behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I was able to access the redux store in my reducers when simply `console.log()`s were not working was as follows:

First import `current` like:

```
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
```

then you can print the values like:

```
reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      // some stuff
      console.log('==>state:');
      console.log(current(state));
    },
```

! WARNING! : Since the redux store is in a wrapper, simply console logging it would print: `Proxy(Object)...`

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you need to define the store in the `window` object (You can place it in you `configureStore` file):

```
window.store = store;
```

Then you only need to write in the console the following:

```
window.store.getState();
```

Hop this helps.

Comment: store is undefined in the console by default. How does it get there?

Comment: Store would need to be defined first in the window object before it can be used.

Comment: @RafaelRozon Yeah, you're right, I've edited my answer in order to show that.

Comment: don't know why people are giving it thumbs down ... this is a very good way.