# Redux security - Is it possible to access store data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm making an app which holds sensitive information about the user. This data is held in the store and is used throughout the app, on different views.

The session can expire, with the store being completely cleared if the user tries to navigate to another route after a timeout. However, the store is not cleared until the user navigates to a new route. Let's say the user leaves their machine without logging out. The session times out but the page is still there and the store is yet to be cleared.

Would it be possible for someone else to access information from the store if it hasn't been cleared yet? (e.g. With Chrome dev tools)

The other option I can see is to clear the store on session timeout and somehow keep the current view in place. The idea being that the current view should not break if the session has expired.

Comment: Anything in page memory/javascript/the browser can be accessed by anyone using that browser

Comment: There is no solution to storing sensitive information in the browser... by definition you've delivered it to the client, you can't hope to control it after that.

Comment: If you don't dispatch an action after the data was cleared, I guess the view won't change. And yes, one can view the data through the react dev tools in chrome

Comment: The state in react/redux represents what is displayed in UI. If the data is in the state, it means it is/can be displayed in UI. There is no need for somebody to look into the store if they can simply look into the UI and find that info (or into the HTML/DOM, which is more easily accessible than JS memory).

Comment: @Sulthan I'm talking about the whole store. It can hold lots of information from other pages too, not all of it is in the DOM at that time.

Comment: Potentially, you could set a `sessionHasTimedOut` flag when the `CLEAR_DATA` action is raised and use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) functions on any redux connected components to cancel the update if the flag is present.  The number of components that would need to implement this might make it a bit prohibitive though.