# Does storing redux state in local storage is recommended?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am using **redux** as state management in my application . I also use **store** concept and store the state in **local storage** for showing the state value even after the page refresh  working fine but my concern is the states stored is exposed to the user . Is that a concern if yes how can I handle that

Comment: This question is likely to insight opinion based answers, so may not be the best for SO. See these instead: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app for more details

Comment: @OliverRadini i too refered that link before but they used localstorage to store the state but I'm asking is saving the data in localstorage is safer to attacks or we having any alternative way to do so

Comment: I think you're asking a different question, then; is it safe to store data in local storage? In which case see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74155/how-secure-is-localstorage

Comment: Whenever we call an action it update the store and create a brand new object completely . How you are going to use local storage?

Comment: const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('state') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : {};

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    persistedState,
    composedEnhancers
);

Comment: I think the question does not even relate to redux store, but can be generally reduced to: Should I store sensitive data in in local storage? NO, never.

Should I store irrelevant state (is sidebar open?) in local storage? Yeah, why not.

Basically you can say that with the right tools you can access the store anyhow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373462/while-debugging-can-i-have-access-to-the-redux-store-from-the-browser-console

Comment: You should read this as well: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: `const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('state') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')) : {};` this is my code for storing the persistedState to avoid state loss on page refresh without localstorage how could i store in redux store @larrydahooster